# ORACLE SQLで全ての表に格納されている列名を取得したい。

Tags: csv, oracle

質問　データーベースに保管されている全ての表の列名情報を取得したいと思います。

環境　OS Windows7
ソフト　ORACLE SQL developmer3
格納表数　57

やりたいこと
　　　ある列名がどの表にあるか調べる

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> やりたいこと
> 　　　ある列名がどの表にあるか調べる

次のSQLで取得できるはずです(環境がなく実際に実行したわけではありません)。

```
select TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME from DBA_TAB_COLS where COLUMN_NAME = '列名';
```

次のマニュアルを参考に回答しています。
[Oracle(R) Databaseリファレンス 12c リリース1 (12.1) 6.41 DBA_TAB_COLS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57425_01/121/REFRN/GUID-857C32FD-AE30-4AB9-811B-AC3A7B91A04D.htm)

19cについても調べてみましたが問題はなさそうです。
相当古いバージョンでもこのSQLで「列名からテーブル名を調べる」ことができると思います。

ALL_TAB_COLUMNSを使っても同様の結果が得られますが、次の違いがあるようです。

- 現行のユーザーがアクセスできる表、ビューおよびクラスタの列が対象
- 非表示列が表示されない